# Script to change the common column in USER_ROLES_PRIVS table

Tags: oracle

Can you let me know the script in oracle to change the common column in USER_ROLES_PRIVS table. Currently it is set to No but i need to change it to yes, Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your current SQL query and what kind of issue you have with it.

Comment: I am using querySELECT * FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS; and in the output of this i have a granted_role as DBA for user C##Scott but if you see in the image the common column is showing NO , I just want to make it yes.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think that you need to change it to "yes"?

---

If you planned to mess up with Oracle data dictionary, don't do that.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-E4C58595-C3C6-4443-9D08-032C7471B7DF.htm#REFRN26230) (12c; that value doesn't exist in lower versions) says that `common`

> Indicates how the grant was made. Possible values:
>
> - YES if the role was granted commonly (CONTAINER=ALL was used)
> - NO if the role was granted locally (CONTAINER=ALL was not used)

Now that you know it, use `container=all` while granting the role.

Comment: HI, Thanks for the reply but i am using the script:

grant DBA to c##SCOTT with container=all option;


and I am getting the error 
Error report -
ORA-01939: only the ADMIN OPTION can be specified
01939. 00000 -  "only the ADMIN OPTION can be specified"
*Cause:    System privileges and roles can only be granted with the admin
           option. The grant option cannot be used with system privileges and
           roles. The delegate option cannot be used with system privileges.
*Action:   Specify the admin option.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know what you used, but - Oracle says that you didn't use what you said you were. Just re-grant it and see what happens.

Comment: Hi

I have used in SQL plus  grant container=all to c##SCOTT

but again i am getting the error : ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege

Comment: Which Oracle database version do you use?

Comment: "Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0"

Comment: Shouldn't that have been e.g. `grant create session to c##scott container=all;`? Statement you posted 5 hours ago is wrong itself.

Comment: Hi , yes this query works but it works for table USER_SYS_PRIVS but i want to change the column for the table USER_ROLE_PRIVS where granted_role is DBA , attached in the screenshot when i post the question.Thanks

Comment: Hi Littlefoot,



Is there any way to change the value in table USER_ROLE_PRIVS for the column common from no to yes?

Comment: I don't have 19c to try it myself, but I presume that the principle is the same.